# How could we understand that the right triangles of trigonometry with a hypotenuse of measure 1 represent all possible right triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The similarity of triangles gives rise to trigonometry.
How could we understand that the right triangles of trigonometry with a hypotenuse of measure 1 represent all possible right triangles? Ultimately, the similarity of triangles is the basis for proportions between sides of two triangles, and these proportions allow for the calculations of which we are speaking here. The similarity of triangles is the foundation of trigonometry.

---

I was asked this question by my Professor. I don't quite understand the question (and English sentence) very well. Because I learned that the ratios of a right triangle is:

$1:1:\sqrt{2}$
where the ratio is order by `adjacent : opposite : hypotenus`.

So the question is:

How come the right triangles of trigonometry with a hypotenuse of measure **1** represent all possible right triangles?

Comment: Because of Thales' theorem.

Comment: The right triangle with sides $(3,4,5)$ doesn't respect the ratio that you gave. But if we are talking about isosceles triangles, the pythagorean theorem should give some clue of what's behind.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question with your answers, please? @Bernard

Comment: Can you please clarify the question with your answer, please? @Souza

Comment: A right triangle with leg lengths $a$ and $b$ and hypotenuse $c$ is similar to (and has the same trig ratios as) the right triangle with sides $a/c, b/c, 1$. Are you asking something else?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you understand that $1:\frac32$ is the same ratio as $2:3$ and the same as $\frac23:1$?

Comment: Thanks for comment, @DavidK . Now, I'm becoming more clear to understand because of your comment.

Comment: Geometrically there are various ways of deploying a circle to show that all possible angles are realised in a right-angled triangle of unit hypotenuse (there are versions where the radius or the diameter can be the hypotenuse)